# Does PostgreSQL deduplicate subqueries?

Tags: postgresql, performance, subquery

For example, do these differ in performance?

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE a.col = b.col) AS e
FROM a
WHERE e
```

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE a.col = b.col)
FROM a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE a.col = b.col)
```

Comment: Please use `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for both statements and see the difference. If you need further help, please post these results as plain text in your question. The DDL for the tables and indexes involved would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery will be evaluated twice. In your artificial case, you can avoid that by writing `SELECT TRUE FROM a WHERE ...`, but there is no general solution that works for every query.